# Enum rawValue of color doesn't produce any color

Tags: swiftui, colors

I am currently following Apple Developer Tutorial but i am stuck at the enum color step. My code doesn't have error i followed their code strictly here is a short code similar to my full code.

Problem here is when i call mainColor it never return any color and i always see a default color in all my view. Could you help me with this and why Apple Code give different result?

```
enum Theme: String {
  case bubblegum
  case buttercup
  case tan
  case teal
  case yellow

  var mainColor: Color {
    Color(rawValue)
  }
  }
```

if i give my view direct initialized value like .orange it works.

Answer (score 4):

The `Color(rawValue)` here is a value of String which equals to `Color("color name")`.

`Color("color name")` is different from `Color.colorname`. You are supposed to create your own colors in the asset folder of your project.

However, I believe that at the start of every tutorial, Apple usually provides resource for the coding part, you should check it, otherwise just create your own colors.

Answer (score 3):

Because `Color(rawValue)` needs to have a value in **Assets** with the name of the `rawValue`.

You need a "Color Set" in "Assets" named "bubblegum", etc (case sensitive)